# AFNetworking return 400 bad request

Tags: ios, iphone, post, afnetworking

i want to post image by `AFNetworking`,here is the code

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager POST:URL parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData){
     [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selfPhoto, 1) name:@"file" fileName:imageFilePath mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
 }
```

but return 400 bad request,here is the errro:

> Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request 
>   failed: bad request (400)"
>   UserInfo={com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response= { URL: http://121.42.203.122:8080/8minutes/uploadImg }
>   { status code: 400, headers {
>       Connection = close;
>       "Content-Language" = en;
>       "Content-Length" = 1105;
>       "Content-Type" = "text/html;charset=utf-8";
>       Date = "Fri, 11 Dec 2015 05:36:46 GMT";
>       Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1"; } }

here is webservice url key:

```
  param:{"file"}
```

where i was wrong?

Comment: 400 Bad request means, you didn't form the request the way server expects. Check the server logs for whats the issue.. May be it needs the image to be sent as multipart/form

Answer (score 3):

Its because the response you are getting is in "**text/html**" format it should be in **application/json** format.

Comment: You need to set content type application/json in your webservice.

Answer (score 0):

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html", nil];
```

try this ...worked for me ...